# Unable to construct python class

Tags: python

I have the following functions, that are working within the boundaries on the Python script

The `loop_vcenters` function will return a dictinary with `cluster: host
subs_per_socket`  function will return the number of sockets for esx

```
def loop_vcenters(vcenters):
    #------------------------- connect to vcenter ----------------------------------------
    si = SmartConnect(host = vcenters,user = 'username',pwd = 'password' ,sslContext=context)
    # disconnect from vcenter one done
    atexit.register(Disconnect, si)
    #get the object content from vcenter
    content = si.RetrieveContent()
    #list clusters
    cluster_host_dic_list=[]
    cluster_name = ""
    for cluster_obj in get_obj(content, vim.ComputeResource):
        cluster=cluster_obj.name
        hosts=[]
        for host in cluster_obj.host:
            hosts.append(host.name)
        #create dictinary ,key=cluster value=esx
        cluster_dic={cluster:hosts}
        cluster_host_dic_list.append(cluster_dic)
    return cluster_host_dic_list

def subs_per_socket(host):
    shost = content.searchIndex.FindByDnsName(dnsName=host, vmSearch=False)
    socket_count = shost.summary.hardware.numCpuPkgs
    sub_per_socket = socket_count/2
    return sub_per_socket
```

I want to put both functions into a class, but I cannot figure out how

```
class loop_vcenters:    
    def hosts_dic(self,name):
        si = SmartConnect(host = vcenters,user = 'username',pwd = 'password' ,sslContext=context)
        atexit.register(Disconnect, si)
        content = si.RetrieveContent()
        cluster_host_dic_list=[]
        cluster_name = ""
        for cluster_obj in get_obj(content, vim.ComputeResource):
            cluster=cluster_obj.name
            hosts=[]
            for host in cluster_obj.host:
                hosts.append(host.name)
            cluster_dic={cluster:hosts}
            cluster_host_dic_list.append(cluster_dic)
      return cluster_host_dic_list
```

1. I am unable to get the host dictionary like the `loop_vcenters` function returned.

```
d = loop_vcenters('vcenters')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
  File "", line 5, in __init__
NameError: global name 'vcenters' is not defined
```

2. How can I add the `subs_per_socket(host)` function to the class?

Comment: In the `loop_vcenters` function, you used the argument `vcenters`, but `hosts_dic` uses `name`. So to Python, the `vcenters` variable must come from an outer (in this case global) scope

Answer (score 0):

```
d = loop_vcenters('vcenters')
```

You are calling the class loop_vcenters with an argument when no **init** is defined.

File "", line 5, in **__init__**

NameError: global name **'vcenters'** is not defined

If you want to pass the argument to host_dic, you should be calling

```
d = loop_vcenters.host_dic('vcenters')
```

which will return cluster_host_dic_list to the variable d.

To add subs_per_socket(host), just define it under the class just as you did the other function.